# Django model inheritence query

Tags: python, django

Say I have this class in an app:

```
class Something(models.Model):
    pass
```

But I don't want this class to inherit from models.Model, I want it to inherit from my own custom class, let's call this 'BetterModel'.

Multiple inheritence doesn't work in this situation so I can't do:

```
import Something
class newClass(Something, BetterModel):
    pass
```

Are there any other options other fork the app?

Comment: You say "But I don't want this class to inherit from models.Model" but you don't say why. Any Django model class *has* to inherit from `models.Model`, directly or indirectly. Otherwise it doesn't get in the database.

Comment: sorry, it's a hypothetical situation.  I should have mentioned BetterModel also inherits from models.Model

Answer (score 2):

You can just directly import your parent "BetterModel". As long as better model implements models.Model you should be good.

Additionally, Django does support multiple inheritance of models so you should be able to extend two different classes as long as they extend models.Model.

Additional Resources:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#model-inheritance
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#multiple-inheritance